# What MediaWiki-oriented or forked CMS will you recommend?

Tags: mediawiki

I have an all-core MediaWiki website and I think to try an architecturally-similar yet simpler CMS but with these features:

- Easy migration path between the two CMSs.
- More control over locking down content for different types of *registered user roles*.
- Better RTL support (most desirably a built-in template to create footnotes via a template with a *template call* such as `{{הערה|תוכן_ללא_מרכאות_וללא_קריאה_לפרמטר|שם="שם_בתוך_מרכאות"}}` but without necessitating Lua/Scribunto extensions.
- ContactPage or similar extension as part of core so that anonymous users would also be able to send email and not only registered users, without requiring a user to install an extension for that *desired state* (thus uppering the chance to stay "all core").
- *Not mandatory but very desirable:* An easy built-in way to implement Google Adsense.

Please recommend one or more **notable** (to be somewhat Wikipedian here for a moment) CMS/s that was or were inspirationally-developed or forked out from MediaWiki.

### Interim notes

- The Hebrew template means a code with this logic:

```
{{footnote
    |FOOTNOTE_CONTENT_WITHOUT_QUOTE_MARKS_AND_WITHOUT_PARAMETER_CALL
    |name="FOOTNOTE_NAME_WRAPPED_WITH_QUOTE_MARKS"
}}
```

But it must all be in Hebrew or at least in another RTL language and easy to translate from *that RTL language* to *another RTL language* (in my case Hebrew).

### My question

Because I don't know of a way to know what this or these was or were for certain, I ask:
What MediaWiki-oriented or forked CMS will you recommend?

Comment: Thanks, George! And please keep in mind that when using terms like "better", "easier", "simpler", they need a "reference point". So please describe what's "wrong" (constructing an example, which might be wrong but hopefully shows what I mean: "while RTL support basically works, it sets punctuation marks on the wrong side" (I know that can be a problem with RTL, hence I've picked that)), or "too complicated", etc.

Comment: Kol ha-kavod! And it looks like my example hit the nail, the quotes look strange :D // I'm cleaning up comments then. Good luck! // Leaving https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software here as reference ;)

Comment: Oh and BTW a nice discussion that you and others might find interesting (or at least parts from it): https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Vlrkuw07aino1gqx